# Interrupt Thread (Java) não mata a execução no banco de dados Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Caros, estou trabalhando em um executor de scripts **PL/SQL**, usando o **JDBC Statement** para fazer minhas conexões com o banco.
O meu problema é que o projeto trabalha com Threads e quando o usuário quer interromper a execução de algum script, eu uso o `interrupt()` o que acaba interrompendo a Thread de fato, porém o script ainda continua em execução e quando eu visualizo a situação do SID na sessão do banco, ele ainda está como **ativo**. Realizando outros testes, onde esse script escreve algo em disco, ele continua aumentando mesmo depois do `interrupt()` na Thread.
Já tentei forçar o `statement.close()` e o `statement.cancel()`, porém sem sucessos.

Aqui está a minha classe que executa o script:

```
package com.dxc.scheduler.repository;

import static com.dxc.scheduler.exception.JobInterruptedException.checkInterruptedThread;
import static java.lang.String.format;
import static java.util.Optional.empty;
import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.dxc.commons.exception.FailureException;
import com.dxc.commons.slf4j.Logger;
import com.dxc.commons.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.dxc.scheduler.domain.Step;
import com.dxc.scheduler.exception.JobInterruptedException;
import com.dxc.scheduler.exception.StepException;

public class OracleRepository implements DatabaseRepository {

    private static final String JOBID_KEY = "job_id";
    private static final String SEQUENCE_KEY = "sequence";

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleRepository.class);

    private static final String DML_SESSION_ID = "SELECT sid FROM V$SESSION WHERE audsid = userenv('sessionid')";

    private static final String DBMSOUTPUT_ENABLE = "begin dbms_output.enable(); end;";
    private static final String DBMSOUTPUT_DISABLE = "begin dbms_output.disable(); end;";
    private static final Integer DBMSOUTPUT_BUFFER = 100_000_000;
    private static final int DBMSOUTPUT_LINES = 100_000_000;

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public OracleRepository(final DataSource ds) {
        if (ds == null) {
            throw new FailureException(
                    "invalid datasource, please use the OracleRepositoryHandler.getDataSource() method to get a valid datasource.");
        }

        dataSource = ds;
    }

    private void enableOrDisableOutput(final Statement st, final boolean enable) throws SQLException {
        st.executeUpdate(enable ? DBMSOUTPUT_ENABLE : DBMSOUTPUT_DISABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public String execute(final Step step) throws SQLException, JobInterruptedException {
        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection(); Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
            try {
                enableOrDisableOutput(st, true);

                LOGGER.info().message("running script...")
                        .extra("script_name", step.getScriptName(), JOBID_KEY, step.getJob().getId(), SEQUENCE_KEY, step.getSequence()).log();

                final String script = wrapScriptInTheTemplate(step);
                LOGGER.trace().message(script).log();
                st.executeUpdate(script);

                LOGGER.info().message("getting output script...")
                        .extra("script_name", step.getScriptName(), JOBID_KEY, step.getJob().getId(), SEQUENCE_KEY, step.getSequence()).log();

                return getOutput(conn);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                checkInterruptedThread();

                String output = "";
                try {
                    output = getOutput(conn);
                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                    LOGGER.warn().message("could not get the script output")
                            .extra("script_name", step.getScriptName(), JOBID_KEY, step.getJob().getId(), SEQUENCE_KEY, step.getSequence())
                            .log();
                }
                throw new StepException(e.getMessage(), output, e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    enableOrDisableOutput(st, false);
                } catch (final SQLException e) {
                    LOGGER.error().message("could not disable the output...")
                            .extra(JOBID_KEY, step.getJob().getId(), SEQUENCE_KEY, step.getScriptName(), "error", e.getMessage()).log();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String getOutput(final Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        Array array = null;

        try (CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall(getScriptOuputLines(DBMSOUTPUT_LINES))) {
            call.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY");
            call.execute();
            array = call.getArray(1);

            final String output = Stream.of((Object[]) array.getArray()).filter(v -> v != null).map(Object::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

            LOGGER.debug().message("the script output was retrieved").extra("lenght", output.length()).log();

            return output;
        } finally {
            if (array != null) {
                array.free();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getScriptOuputLines(final int number) {
        return format("declare num integer := %d; begin dbms_output.get_lines(?, num); end;", number);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.AvoidBranchingStatementAsLastInLoop")
    public Optional<Integer> getSessionId() throws SQLException {
        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection(); PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(DML_SESSION_ID)) {
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    final int sessionId = rs.getInt(1);
                    LOGGER.debug().message("the session id was retrieved").extra("session_id", sessionId).log();
                    return ofNullable(sessionId);
                }
            }
        }
        return empty();
    }

    private String wrapScriptInTheTemplate(final Step step) {
        return format("begin dbms_output.enable(%d); dbms_application_info.set_action('%s_%s_%s'); %s end;", DBMSOUTPUT_BUFFER,
                step.getJob().getType(), step.getJob().getSource(), step.getSequence(), step.getSource());
    }

}
```

Aqui está o endpoint que eu uso para interromper a execução:

```
@ResponseBody
@PutMapping("jobs/{id}/interrupt")
public ResponseEntity<?> interrupt(@PathVariable final Long id, @RequestHeader("X-SCHEDULER2-APIKEY") final Optional<String> token) {

    final Optional<ResponseEntity<?>> res = checkAPIToken(token);
    if (res.isPresent()) {
        return res.get();
    }

    final Optional<Job> job = jobRepository.findByIdAndStatus(id, JobStatus.RUNNING);
    if (job.isPresent()) {
        jobLifecycleManager.interrupt(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ACCEPTED);
    }
    final ErrorDataResponse response = new ErrorDataResponse(of("job not found or job is not in running"), NOT_FOUND);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, response.getHttpStatus());
}
```

Aqui o método chamado que redireciona para a classe que executa o script e o finaliza no "finally" do exception:

```
public void interrupt(final Long jobId) {
    final Optional<JobMetadata> jm = get(jobId);
    if (jm.isPresent()) {
        final long threadId = jm.get().getThreadId();
        getAllStackTraces().keySet().stream().filter(t -> t.getId() == threadId).forEach(t -> t.interrupt());
    }
}
```

E após isso, é atualizado o status do script no banco, como **interrompido**.
Por que mesmo após interromper a thread o script ainda continua rodando?

Comment: Nosso idioma é o **Portugues**. Traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: São scripts PL/SQL ou Stored Procedures? A nomenclatura é importante. Scripts PL/SQL não sei do que se trata. Stored Procedures rodam dentro do SGBD/DBMS e não creio que possam ser interrompidas só matando a thread que as chamou.

Comment: São scripts PL/SQL mesmo. Com DECLARE, BEGIN e END.

Answer (score 2):

A partir do momento que você mandou o script rodar acredito que parar a Thread já não vai mais adiantar, você vai ter que mandar um

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';
```

depois de interromper a Thread, cria um Statement e passa o comando...

Comment: E quando eu não possuo esse privilégio na base?